# Can I use pivot to get counts for each value groups on MSSQL?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, integer, pivot

I have a lot of numbers to group.

**UPDATE:**
These are in one column, and the below is the result of 'select col from table'

```
col
12
11
23
22
41
12
37
15
41
23
77
.
.
more
.
```

I want to get a table like below.

```
0~9    10~19    20~29    30~39    40~49    50~59    60~
1      5        4        6        5        2        3
```

Is this possible with pivot? or just I need to do something like

```
CASE WHEN COL>=0 AND COL<10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS '0~9'
...
```

with a bunch of case-whens?

Comment: I think you'll need both. First a query to generate the column for range and then a query to pivot.

Comment: Are those numbers in a row or in a column?  It's not exactly clear from your question.

Comment: in a column. sorry for confusion.

Comment: If you are not fussy about the columns names, just pivot on the result of an integer divide by 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are wanting to solve **THIS** very specific example, you could use:

```
select [0] [0˜9], [1] [10˜19], [2] [20˜29], [3] [30˜39], [4] [40˜49], [5] [50˜59], [6] [60˜]
from Table1
cross apply (select case when number >= 60 then 6 else cast(number/10 as int) end) N(Decade)
pivot (count(number) for Decade in ([0],[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6]))  A
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/30544c/13/0)

**UPDATE**

Based on OP own answer, the answer that would work for his case is:

```
select [0] [0˜9], [1] [10˜19], [2] [20˜29], [3] [30˜39], [4] [40˜49], [5] [50˜59], [6] [60˜]
from (select number from Table1) O
cross apply (select case when number >= 60 then 6 else cast(number/10 as int) end) N(Decade)
pivot (count(number) for Decade in ([0],[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6]))  A
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/850a5/3)

Comment: This gave me the result of 'select case when x>0 and x<10 then 1 else 0 end as 'col1', case when......' without group by. but the main idea [cast(number/10 as int)] was really helpful. Thanks.

Comment: I really didn't understand. What is the difference? The results seems the same and the pivot is already aggregating values. Would you give me an example where this result doesn't apply please?

Comment: Please refer the updates of my answer. and there can be errors on my answer (I try to use the exact method & grammar, but I'm almost new to mssql :( ), so if you find any errors, you are always welcome.

Comment: Now I checked SQL Fiddle, and now I see you gave me the exact answer. I couldn't see it before, because they gave me an error (not user SQL error, but some kind of connection error or whatever). anyway, I use MSSQL 2012, but I don't think that makes any difference, and I don't know where to point for explaining the difference between SQL Fiddle & MSSQL 2012, so if you find any, please share for good, or if you're busy, Thanks anyway.:)

Comment: The diffence is that your table has another columns and the query was counting the values segreggated by the other columns. To solve this, it is only necessary to select only one call in from subquery. It WAS agreggating values, but like you where using `GROUP BY` of all other columns. To make it clearer for you, in the 1st query, replace `[0] [0˜9], [1] [10˜19], [2] [20˜29], [3] [30˜39], [4] [40˜49], [5] [50˜59], [6] [60˜]` by `*`, if you are interested.

Comment: Ah.. right. Why couldn't I think about that.. Thanks for everything!

Answer (score 0):

This is a result for me.

```
select [0] [0˜9], [1] [10˜19], [2] [20˜29], [3] [30˜39], [4] [40˜49], [5] [50˜59], [6] [60˜]
from
(select case when number_column >= 60 then 6 else cast(number_column/10 as int) end as decade
from original_table) as source_table
pivot (
count(decade) for decade in ([0],[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6])
) as pivot_table
```

and thanks Pieter Geerkens & Nizam for giving me the clues.

**UPDATE:**
If there're other columns which are not used for pivoting in the table, the result can be like below.

Nizam's 1st suggestion.
[image: Case 1]

To solve this please refer 
1. Nizam's updated suggestion.
or
2. Below

[image: Case 2]